# Playing music on Skype while talking on the microphone

Tags: skype

I want to play music on Skype and at the some time talk with my partner through mic. On some occasions I have no problem doing this and the music is allowed through the mic to be heard on the other side. But strangely on some occasions my partner can hear me but can't hear the music. In some way the sound of music is blocked by Skype. How can I solve the problem/ Please note that I don't have "Stereo Mix" installed and my system is 8.1. 
Can I solve this problem by audio settings in Skype?

Comment: The problem is actually the other way around.  It is a normal process to want to block the feedback, and also to reduce the data needed to ensure a stable connection.

Answer (score 1):

I use a program call Voicemeeter for this. Using these settings:
[image]

You can set Windows Media Player to play Music via the "Voicemeeter virtual audio" output, and set Skype to use the Voicemeeter Virtual Audio Input. 
Then with the settings above, you can listen to the music too and maintain a decent volume level easily. Deselecting "A" will stop you hearing yourelf